# ¿Como abrir un excel con contraseña?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

Necesito trabajar con los datos contenidos en un excel **protegido con contraseña** (conociendo la contraseña). ¿Hay algún método para poder pasar la contraseña como parámetro al abrir el archivo?

He mirado la documentación de openpyxl y parece que no se contempla esta opción.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encontré [una solución en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50081033/11649862) que podrías adaptar a tu necesidad. Es usando el paquete `xlwings`:

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd


filename = "pwdtest.xlsx"
password = "test"

wb = xw.Book(filename, password=password)

sheet = wb.sheets[0]
df = sheet.used_range.options(pd.DataFrame, header=True, index=False).value
```

Debería devolver el contenido de la primera hoja correctamente como un DataFrame

Comment: Gracias! Esta solución parece la más viable en este momento, y funciona perfectamente, aunque me obliga a cargar un paquete que no tenía (pensaba que era de pago, pero veo que hay alguna opción free).

Comment: La versión pro de XLWings es más orientada para deployment. Imagino que solo estás usando un script, por lo que la gratuita debería ser suficiente.

Comment: Si, si, solo es un script, aunque debería usarlo en varios ordenadores diferentes. En uno de ellos, algo antiguo, con W7 y 32 bits, no logro que funcione. No doy con la versióna instalar, pero eso es tema de otra pregunta, jejeje... voy a seguir investigando.

Answer (score 4):

Para recapitular y añadir mi propia investigación al respecto. He probado muchas opciones y código en busca de lo que necesitaba, y aquí va el resultado:

**Solución con openpyxl:**
`openpyxl` ofrece protección a los libros de trabajo de excel, pero solo para que no se pueda modificar la estructura, [link](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protection.html):  y esto no sirve para evitar que otros usuarios puedan ver la información, o cambiarla.
Después de hacer varias pruebas, si nuestro libro de excel ya tiene contraseña, no podremos abrirlo (el script genera un error); y si creamos el libro de excel con un script y le asignamos una contraseña, excel (mi versión -2019-) no lo reconoce como un fichero válido y no lo abrirá, sin embargo, podremos recuperar la información mediante python sin problemas. Como esta no era la intención al formular la pregunta, esta opción queda descartada.

**Solución con xlwings:**
La segunda opción, apuntada por @DannyTalent, usando el módulo `wlwings`, con el código que él mismo proporcionó, funciona perfectamente, y cumple con el requisito de abrir el archivo excel con contraseña y poder trabajar con él de forma bastante cómoda, y aunque es un paquete de pago, la versión free será suficiente para este propósito.

**Solución con win32com:**
Y la tercera opción, que apuntaba @Carlos E. Ferro y que me animó a seguir investigando, consiste en usar la interface COM de ExcelWorkbooks. El módulo `pywin32` (win32com) nos proporciona herramientas para conseguir algo parecido a nuestro objetivo, pero que puede ser util. En este caso, lo que hace el código es abrir el archivo de excel, quitar la password, y dejarlo listo para trabajar con otros módulos (como `openpyxl`). Después de eso, podemos volver a usar win32com para asignar de nuevo una password al archivo excel. Una opción un poco más elaborada, pero que nos permitirá trabajar con el excel libremente. Dejo aquí el código que he usado, por si alguien prefiere este último método.

```
import win32com.client

archivo = "MyFile.xlsx"
pw_str  = 'pass'
pw_none = ''
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(archivo, False, False, None, pw_str)
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
# Establezca la contraseña de acceso al guardar.
wb.SaveAs(archivo, None, pw_none, pw_none)
excel.Quit()
```

En este caso, habría que invertir las variables `pw_str` y `pw_none` al abrir y cerrar el archivo de excel, para poner/quitar la password.

Gracias a los que han colaborado en encontrar una solución.

Answer (score 0):

En la interface COM de ExcelWorkboks, la colección de libros abiertos, el método Open tiene 15 parámetros y sólo el primero es requerido, lso demás son opcionales. El quinto es la password.

1       'Filename'
2       'UpdateLinks'
3       'ReadOnly'
4       'Format'
5       'Password'
6       'WriteResPassword'
7       'IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended'
8       'Origin'
9       'Delimiter'
10      'Editable'
11      'Notify'
12      'Converter'
13      'AddToMru'
14      'Local'
15      'CorruptLoad'

No sé cómo hace openpyxl, pero es muy probable que use la interfaz COM y se pueda hacer otra versión del Open que utilice más parámetros.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Por lo que he visto, el paquete xlwings al que se hace referencia en una respuesta anterior, usa esta interface y permite abrir el archivo. Es una lástima que los chicos de openpyxl no lo hayan implementado. ¡A ver en el futuro!